# Can't set margin on Nativescript ProxyViewContainer programmatically

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

The angular team has the package [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) which I use extensively in my codebase. I am converting many of these core components to also be used on mobile devices through Nativescript and to that end have created my own component to mimic the flex-layout functionality. FlexboxLayout does everything I need this component to do natively **except** provide a mechanism for spacing the laid out components with a uniform gap between them. (NOTE: **Not** space-between as gaps resulting from that are not uniform). Basically, flex-layout puts a right-margin equal to the gap size if layout is row and a bottom-margin if layout is column. Here is my code to try to do the same in Nativescript that does not work for me.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { FlexboxLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/flexbox-layout";
import { View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view";

@Component({
    selector: "flex-layout",
    template: `
        <FlexboxLayout
            #flexbox
            [flexDirection]="layout"
            [flexWrap]="wrap"
            [justifyContent]="justify"
            [alignItems]="align"
            [ngStyle]="{ width: width, height: height }"
        >
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    `
})
export class FlexLayoutComponent {
    @Input() layout: string = "row";
    @Input() wrap: string;
    @Input() justify: string;
    @Input() align: string = "start";
    @Input() gap: number;
    @Input() width: number;
    @Input() height: number;
    @ViewChild("flexbox") flexboxEl: ElementRef;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        let flexbox: FlexboxLayout = <FlexboxLayout>(
            this.flexboxEl.nativeElement
        );
        if (this.gap) {
            flexbox.eachChildView((child: View) => {
                if (this.layout === "row") {
                    child.marginRight = this.gap;
                } else {
                    child.marginBottom = this.gap;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the margin like this seems to have no affect on the components.

A more welcome solution is one in which I don't have to create this component myself at all. That is, am I missing some obvious layout type/parameter that would do this for me already?

### UPDATE

I have found the issue to be limited to children that are ProxyViewContainers then the setting of the margin does not work. Setting the margin on native components work fine.  But the former is what nearly all of my cases are since I'm building cross purpose (web and nativescript) components. Custom angular components show up as ProxyViewContaners and the setting of the margin does not seem to work on those. [Here is a playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=A3ovY5) demonstrating this. Native components get their margins set, ProxyViewContainers do not. Checking the grand-children of these ProxyViewContainers is not a solution because a) There can be more than one child and I want only a single margin applied to the parent and b) even if it is a single component it is also most likely to be a ProxyViewContainer itself!

### UPDATE 2

It looks like this is not possible at present. You cannot directly style custom components in nativescript-angular. I just found an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1547) that I think would exactly solve my issue here.

### UPDATE 3

I have what will hopefully be a functional work-around for now. I have tested it in the playground linked above and it is working for that simple case. The work-around comes both from the issue mentioned in Update 2 and also in [this closed issue too](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1691). Thanks to those programmers for their help. Basically it involves registering your custom-component element (through its selector) to use a StackLayout (or whichever layout you want). This is done globally so you can put it in the module where you declare this component or I guess at the top of each component's code? e.g.

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
import { StackLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout";
registerElement('my-component-selector', () => StackLayout);
```

Do this for all the custom components you desire to be able to style.

Comment: Are you sure `this.gap` has a value and passes `if` condition? Do you have a Playground sample?

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you doing that made me realize that the issue is specifically that if the child is a ProxyViewContainer (my test cases) then the margin setting does not work. It does work for native components though. See playground that I added.

Comment: When it's a custom component, it should accept `margin` as an `@Input()` and bind it to margin property of `Label` within `my-label`.

Comment: Nice idea but not applicable here, see my above reason for that. my-label might have two Labels at the root OR more likely still be made of more custom components. I have custom components dozens deep. Not going to pass margin all the way down!  :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible yet to pass property for root element like Angular Web. You have to do it via @Input, even if you have multiple labels, you can still deal with one input and bind the value to all labels.

Comment: Well I found a work-around for now. See Update 3 above. Cheers.